# Resize Chart inside a pop up in AGOL Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, operations-dashboard

I am trying to fix pop-ups in my ArcGIS Online Dashboard that I am making.

I created the pop-up in a Web Map and everything looks fine:

[image: Web map Pop up that shows pie chart correctly]

However, when I use the Web Map in a dashboard, the popup is changed to include captions which makes the pie chart too small to read:

[image: Dashboard that shows pie chart too small]

I cant seem to make any other changes in the web map, I am hoping that I missed a setting in the Dashboard configuration.

Comment: Is it an option for you to remove the chart from the popup and simply use the built-in chart element on the dashboard?

Comment: I am using a Serial Chart as well which displays a group of bar graphs that displays the same information as my pie chart. It would be ideal if I could have a consistent pop-up between my web map and my dashboard.